# Calculate hours difference between timezone and UTC based timezone name in following format: America/New_York

Tags: python

I have a library which returns the timezone of a location in the format: America/New_York. Based on that timezone name, I want to calculate the hours between that time zone and UTC, taking into account daylight savings time and all. I'm using Python.

My first idea was to use the Google python library and search for 'America/New_York time' but that only gave me back a list of urls which I could visit to get the info myself. It would be awesome if I could get the current time seen if I were to manually search 'America/New_York time' into google, right into my program.

I'm sure this question has been asked before, but I am new to stack overflow and python so help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The offset from UTC depends on the date (since daylight saving time may or may not be in effect).  So you need to provide a datetime for the comparison.

ZoneInfo.utcoffset will return a timedelta object directly.

```py
>>> from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> ZoneInfo("America/New_York").utcoffset(datetime(2021, 10, 23)) #EDT
datetime.timedelta(days=-1, seconds=72000)
>>> ZoneInfo("America/New_York").utcoffset(datetime(2021, 11, 15)) #EST
datetime.timedelta(days=-1, seconds=68400)
>>> ZoneInfo("Asia/Tokyo").utcoffset(datetime(2021, 10, 23))
datetime.timedelta(seconds=32400)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a complete answer, but maybe you could implement a dictionary that connects these format to the normal format with three letters. With this you can then use datetime and pytz to make the rest. If you don't have too many possible outputs in the current format this would be feasible, otherwise of course not.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> from datetime import datetime, timedelta
>>> from datetime import timezone
>>> from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo
>>> dt1 = datetime(2020, 11, 1, 8, tzinfo=timezone.utc)
>>> dt2 = datetime(2020, 11, 1, 8, tzinfo=ZoneInfo("America/New_York"))
>>> dt2 - dt1
datetime.timedelta(seconds=18000)
>>>
```

Note that the difference will be four for five hours depending on whether daylight saving time is in effect or not.